# Cannot add jquery UI button style to all buttons Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, jquery-ui

just want to add jquery UI button style to all buttons in the following way but it does not work. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("button").button();
        });
```

here is the example code of my button(view file):

```
 $data = array(
    'name' => $places_id,
    'class' => 'review',    
    'content' => 'Write a Review'    
    );
   echo form_button($data);
```

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? It tells us very little. Do these buttons exist when initial page loads?

Comment: it means that buttons exist but are not styled in jquery UI way

Comment: did you include proper css file for them and jQueryUI button code? Are errors thrown?

Comment: So... where's Your view file?

Comment: you can see the view file in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to include your JS file :)

Answer (score 1):

I think codeigniter generates the buttons in the format like

`<input type="button" value="xyz">`

**and not**

`<button>xyz</button>`

so 
**instead of**

```
$("button").button();
```

**Try this:**

```
$("input[type=button]").button();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately buttons still are not styled